# Laravel 5.2 SAML2 Authentication persistance issue

Tags: php, laravel-5, saml-2.0

I have installed this github Laravel 5 Saml2 package:
https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2

I've got the login working, authentication is happening and the data is being passed back correctly.  I have a LoginListener that is successfully catching the correct user information and returning a valid user from the database.  However when I attempt to use Auth::login it does not persist outside of the listener handle function and will go into an endless loop between the SAML authentication and the listener.

Here is my Listener:

```
namespace App\Listeners;
use \Aacotroneo\Saml2\Events\Saml2LoginEvent;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;


class LoginListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  Saml2LoginEvent  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Saml2LoginEvent $event)
    {
      $user = $event->getSaml2User();
            $userData = [
                'id' => $user->getUserId(),
                'attributes' => $user->getAttributes(),
                'assertion' => $user->getRawSamlAssertion()
            ];

            //check if email already exists and fetch user
            $user = \App\Models\User::where('username', $userData['attributes']['NameID'][0])->first();
            Auth::guard('web')->login($user);   
            Session::save();        
    }
}
```

I have added 'web' to my routesMiddleware setting in the saml2-settings file as is suggested in multiple places with no effect.  Does someone have a working example of this somewhere that I can dig through to see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this turned out to be in the middleware.  I have several custom middleware files setup and they were interferring with the web middleware begin the solution to the issue.

To solve this I created a custom middlewareGroup in the Kernel called listener and removed all of the extra middleware that I had added to web:

```
'listener' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    ],
```

Then in the saml2_settings config file I changed the routesMiddleware variable to listener:

```
'routesMiddleware' => ['listener'],
```

Hopefully this helps someone else in the troubleshooting process.